# Where to initialize singleton clients in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I'm creating a new Azure Function that will send email notifications. This function, first needs to get users' email addresses from CosmosDB. I have a CosmosDB client wrapper class.

How would I create a singleton instance of my CosmosDB client and use it in my Azure Function? I guess something like the following code could create an instance but how would I make it a singleton?

```
public static class MyFunction
{

    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public static Clients.CosmosDb.CosmosDbClient _cosmosDbClient;

    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("my-queue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem)
    {
        // Create CosmosDb Client
        Initialize();

        // Call CosmosDB
        _cosmosDbClient.Read();
    }

    private static void Initialize()
    {
       if (_cosmosDbClient == null)
           _cosmosDbClient = new Clients.CosmosDb.CosmosDbClient(Configuration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace your `Initialize` with a static constructor:

```cs
static MyFunction()
{
    // load configuration?
    _cosmosDbClient = new Clients.CosmosDb.CosmosDbClient(Configuration);
}
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear, I think you're saying if I create an instance of my CosmosDB client inside a `static` method, it will be a `singleton`, is that right? The `Run()` method is already static. I think you're suggesting I should just `new` up my CosmosDB client there. If that's the case, there isn't much difference between what you're suggesting and my sample code. The intialize function is just to keep things a bit tidier.

Comment: There's just one instance of a static variable, so yes. Your code is almost the same, but you call it in every function call which I'm not a fan of. There might theoretically be a race condition there too, when 2 function calls happen exactly a the same time and 2 clients are created. Matter of taste I guess.

Comment: Got you! I appreciate your response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to use DocumentClient from [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/161)
funcion.json

```
{
 "type": "documentDB",
  "name": "client",
  "connection": "myconnection_DOCUMENTDB",
  "direction": "in"
}
```

C# function

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;

public static void Run(string input, DocumentClient client, TraceWriter log)
{       
  // client has connection string already set up based on binding
}
```

We also have a CosmosDB Attribute defined in [Extensions SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/CosmosDBAttribute.cs). You can this attribute to get access to CosmosDB client. Here is the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/ExtensionsSample/Samples/CosmosDBSamples.cs#L78) to access DocumentClient via CosmosDB attribute.  You can try via [Precompiled Functions in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library). Using DocumentClient provided by the attribute will ensure reusing the connection.